# I keep getting this error on my insert "call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm not sure why I keep getting this error but I need some help with it... I'm just trying to check the db to see of the record exists before allowing an insert.

```
$input_errors = array();

if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
} else {
    $input_errors['username'] = "Must fill out username";
}

$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usermail', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (false === $email) {
    $input_errors['usermail'] = "Not a valid email address";
}

if(count($input_errors) > 0) {
    print_r($input_errors); die();
}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as amount FROM people WHERE username = ? 
       OR email = ?";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->get_result();
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

    if ($data['amount'] > 0)
    {
        print "User already exists";
    }
}

else {
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "Init failed";
} else {
    $cmd = "INSERT INTO people (username, email, sign_up_date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW() )";
    if ($stmt->prepare($cmd)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $email );
        $stmt->execute();

        echo $stmt->affected_rows . " row(s) inserted";

        $stmt->close();

    } else {
        echo "Prepare failed";
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    }
}
```

If anyone can lend a helping hand that would be fantastic.

Comment: `get_result` is only available if you have [mysqlnd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) installed.

Comment: It's super unfortunate, but true. This is one of MySQLi's principal failings and you're stuck with the cumbersome `bind_result()` instead.

Comment: @m59 PDO is _easier_. MySQLi has more features but lots of labyrinths like this to navigate.

Comment: Using `bind_result()` nothing got inserted and no error message.. something broke.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, If i install the native driver I can use my code?

Comment: @cookinggood: Possibly.  Try it and find out ;-)

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if you appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

For some reason I just can't stand such long and windy codes.
All you actually need is just

```
$cmd = "INSERT IGNORE INTO people (username, email, sign_up_date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW() )";
$stmt->prepare($cmd);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $email);
$stmt->execute();
if (!$stmt->affected_rows)
{
    print "User already exists";
}
```

No need to hassle with extra select query.
No need to hassle with binding results.
No need to hassle with numerous nested if statements (whose logic is flawed and actually spoiled the whole mess).

Comment: Lol, I was distracted by the unsupported function and didn't even notice it wasn't needed :) Good job!

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'm still having a problem, what code can i chop because I tried taking out that other statement and it's still running with dupes.

Comment: all the SQL interaction have to be changed for this code. But I forgot an essential thing, I must admit - you have to have an UNIQUE index for the username and email fields.

Comment: Still no progress, I'm in need of more help. I haven't yet changed my username and email to UNIQUE but I can and will if you give me a little more help.

Comment: Nothing is working. In need of help.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your php version is PHP 5.3.0 or higher and you have the `mysqlnd driver` installed on your server. Otherwise, that function is not available.

Instead, you could use [fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).

Comment: Not `fetch_array()` or `fetch_assoc()` though, as those depend on `get_result()` from a prepared statement, no?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski hmm..I guess so. According to the docs it looks like only `fetch()` is supported on the stmt.

Comment: Using fetch() nothing got inserted and no error message.. something broke.  `$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as amount FROM people WHERE username = ? 
       OR email = ?";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetch();
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

    if ($data['amount'] > 0)
    {
        print "User already exists";
    }
}`

Comment: This does not work, still in need of help.

Comment: @cookinggood At a certain point it isn't reasonable for someone else to help you (it's a lot more work for us than for you at this point). Just `var_dump` things each step of the way and see what you're working with. That should help you spot errors and give you more insight into what you're doing.

Comment: using fetch() gives me an identical error.  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Comment: @cookinggood consider that then - if your `$stmt` isn't an object, then `execute()` must not have succeeded.